# Connecting to Many TOR Exit Nodes

Tags: python, tor

I want to develop a distributed web crawler using TOR. How do I have say 20 different connections via TOR going? I want to browse with the website with 20 external ips simultaneously. Code examples in Python please.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)